# Updating textarea rows separately in ReactJS component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, textarea

I have created a ReactJS component for the text area that when clicked, the rows will be updated to 10, then will return to 1 when onblur triggers. It works but when I put it in an array.map, all of the text area will expand to 10 rows when I click a single one. how do I make it so that it would only trigger on the clicked component?

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
const [inputRows, setInputRows] = React.useState(1); 

criteria.children.map((c) => {
      return (
        <tr key={c.key} className="ant-table-row ant-table-row-level-0">
          <td className="ant-table-cell" style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
            <Form.Item
              key={c.key + "_rating"}
              style={{ marginBottom: "0px" }}
              name={c.key + "_rating"}
            >
              <InputNumber
                className={
                  "text-center" +
                  (!isIndexed(c.key) ? " rating_not_indexed" : "")
                }
                formatter={(value) =>
                  `${
                    value.toString().length == 0
                      ? ""
                      : isNaN(Math.round(value * 100) / 100)
                      ? ""
                      : Math.round(value * 100) / 100
                  }`
                }
                min={0}
                max={3}
                step={1}
              />
            </Form.Item>
          </td>
          <td className="ant-table-cell">
            <Tooltip
              placement="right"
              title={form.getFieldValue(c.key + "_comment")}
            >
              <Form.Item
                style={{ marginBottom: "0px" }}
                name={c.key + "_comment"}
              >
                <textarea
                  rows={inputRows}
                  className="textarea"
                  onClick={() => setInputRows(10)}
                  onBlur={() => setInputRows(1)}
                  tabIndex={-1}
                ></textarea>
              </Form.Item>
            </Tooltip>
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have thought of a solution now, since i have may c.key, i used it as an identifier to trigger the row change:

```
const [selectedRow, setSelectedRow] = React.useState("");
const [inputRows, setInputRows] = React.useState(1);

const updateRows = (selected, row) => {
    setSelectedRow(selected);
    setInputRows(row);
};

criteria.children.map((c) => {
      return (
        <tr key={c.key} className="ant-table-row ant-table-row-level-0">
          <td className="ant-table-cell" style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
            ...
          </td>
          <td className="ant-table-cell">
            <Tooltip
              placement="right"
              title={form.getFieldValue(c.key + "_comment")}
            >
              <Form.Item
                style={{ marginBottom: "0px" }}
                name={c.key + "_comment"}
              >
                <textarea
                  rows={selectedRow === c.key ? inputRows : 1}
                  className="textarea"
                  onClick={() => updateRows(c.key, 10)}
                  onBlur={() => updateRows(c.key, 1)}
                  tabIndex={-1}
                ></textarea>
              </Form.Item>
            </Tooltip>
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
```